# Detect presence of a specific charset

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, detection

I need a way to detect whether a file contains characters from a certain charset.

Specifically, I want to detect the presence of UTF8-encoded cyrillic characters in a series of files. Is there a tool to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for ready solution, you might want to try [Enca](http://freshmeat.net/projects/enca/).

However, if you only want to detect presence of what can be possibly decoded as UTF-8 Cyrillic characters (without any complete UTF-8 validity checks), you just have to grep for something like `/(\xD0[\x81\x90-\xBF]|\xD1[\x80-\x8F\x91]){`*n*`,}/` (this exact regexp is for *n* subsequent UTF8-encoded Russian Cyrillic characters). For additional check that the whole file contains only valid UTF-8 data you can use something like [`isutf8(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/isutf8).

Both methods have their good and bad sides and may sometimes give wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC the ICU library has code that does character set detection.  Though it's basically a best effort guess.

Edit: I did remember correctly, check out this [paper / tutorial](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection)

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial is helpful. Bookmarking it for future reference.